# <View /> minHeight based on constant numberOfLines - fontSize in 'rem'

Tags: react-native

```
<View style={{minHeight: ??? }}> // <--- based on a constant maximum value of numberOfLines

    <Text style={{fontSize: '1rem'}}>{someShortOrLongText}<Text>

</View>
```

In a `<View />` I want to render a `<Text />` that is sometimes 1 line long and other times 2 or even 3 lines long.

As it is the `<View />` resizes based on the length of the {someShortOrLongText}.

I am working on a solution to parse all the possible texts before any render and have the **maximum** number of lines stored (for the worst case). For consistency I would like to reserve a minHeight equal to the maximum height that the `<Text />` would occupy in that case.

I could force it to be way bigger but I am seeking a perfect match to not waste any more space than the actual 3 lines (in this case) would occupy.

Is there any way to achieve this if I use `rem` units for my `fontSize`?

Is it a good or bad practice to have height like:

`<View style={{minHeight: '$constantEqualToFontSize * maxNumOfLines'}} />`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to render text based the text size and put it within a view this can help you.

```
 return (
        <View style={{flex: 1}}>
           <View style={{
             borderRadius: 30,
             alignItems: 'center',
             justifyContent: 'center',
             backgroundColor: '#ffd5ab',
             padding: 15, maxWidth: 300
         }}>
                <Text style={{flexShrink: 1}}>
                   {someShortOrLongText}
                </Text>
           </View>
        </View>
 );
```

Here `inner view` will be resized based the text you put within, you can also position the `inner view` as `absolute`.